# How to recursively get categories and their sub categories' sub categories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recursion

I'm trying to draw my website map as follows

```
 <ul>
       <li>Cat1</li>           
       <li>Cat2                
             <ul class='sub2'>                     
                <li>Cat21</li>           
                <li>Cat22</li>
                <li>Cat23
                      <ul class='sub23'>                     
                            <li>Cat231</li>           
                            <li>Cat232</li>
                            <li>Cat233                                
                                   <ul class='sub233'>                     
                                      <li>Cat2331</li>           
                                      <li>Cat2332</li>
                                      <li>Cat2333</li>
                                   </ul>
                            </li>
                      </ul>
                 </li>
             </ul>
       </li>     
       <li>Cat3
             <ul class='sub3'>                     
                <li>Cat31</li>           
                <li>Cat32</li>
                <li>Cat33</li>
             </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Cat4</li>
 </ul>
```

The map provider is a List of PostCategory objects

```
 List<PostCategory> MapProvider=new List<PostCategory>();
///....MapProvider.add(...);
CategoryMapViewModel siteMap=new CategoryMapViewModel(MapProvider);
var map=siteMap.Map.ToString();
```

and the PostCategory object

```
public class PostCategory{
    [Key]
    public int? CategoryId{get;set;}

    [StringLength(20/*50*/,MinimumLength=3)]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //relationship
    public int? IdPostCategoryParent { get; set; }
    }
```

I have written some thing but it doesn't work recursively for subcategories of the subcategories: for example: it works for sub2 but not for sub23, sub332, sub....

here is my CategoryMapViewModel class

```
public class CategoryMapViewModel
{
    public HtmlString Map { get; private set; }
    private List<int?> TakenIds = new List<int?>();
    public CategoryMapViewModel(List<PostCategoryModels> categoriesModels)
    {
        string map = "";
        map = BuildCategoriesMap(categoriesModels, map);
        this.Map = new HtmlString(map);
    }

    private string BuildCategoriesMap(List<PostCategoryModels> categories, string map)
    {
        if (categories != null && categories.Count > 0)
        {
            map += "<ul>";
            foreach (PostCategoryModels cat in categories)
            {
                if ((!cat.CategoryId.HasValue) || (cat.CategoryId.HasValue && (!TakenIds.Contains(cat.CategoryId))))
                {
                    map += "<li>" + cat.Name;
                    List<PostCategoryModels> subCats = categories.Where(c => c.IdPostCategoryParent == cat.CategoryId).ToList();
                    if (subCats.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        //map += BuildCategoriesMap(subCats, map);
                        //BuildCategoriesMap(subCats, map);
                        map += BuildCategoriesMap(subCats, "");
                    }
                    map += "</li>";
                }
                TakenIds.Add(cat.CategoryId);
            }
            map += "</ul>";
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

am I wrong ? can someone give me the best and easiest way to do it ? if yes, please do it!
Kind Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are searching in categories for the children, but when processing the direct children, you only pass the direct children through, so when it searches for sub categories, there are none that match.

One solution is to keep a reference to categories in your class and use that when searching for sub categories.

ie:

```
public class CategoryMapViewModel
{
    public HtmlString Map { get; private set; }
    private List<int?> TakenIds = new List<int?>();
    private List<PostCategoryModels> _categories;

    public CategoryMapViewModel(List<PostCategoryModels> categoriesModels)
    {    
        _categories = categoriesModels ?? new List<PostCategoryModels>();
        string map = BuildCategoriesMap(_categories);
        this.Map = new HtmlString(map);
    }

    private string BuildCategoriesMap(List<PostCategoryModels> categories)
    {
        var map = "";
        if (categories.Count > 0)
        {
            map += "<ul>";
            foreach (PostCategoryModels cat in categories)
            {
                if ((!cat.CategoryId.HasValue) || (cat.CategoryId.HasValue && (!TakenIds.Contains(cat.CategoryId))))
                {
                    map += "<li>" + cat.Name;
                    List<PostCategoryModels> subCats = _categories.Where(c => c.IdPostCategoryParent == cat.CategoryId).ToList();
                    map += BuildCategoriesMap(subCats);
                    map += "</li>";
                }
                TakenIds.Add(cat.CategoryId);
            }
            map += "</ul>";
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

I've taken out a few redundant lines also

Comment: youuuupiiii !!!! Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees !!!! You right and now It works thank you Martin